# Refund a transaction via the measurement protocol - Not Working

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to refund a transaction via the measurement protocol. I'm using the following with a `POST` request:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect/?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXX&cid=555&ec=Ecommerce&ea=Refund&ni=1&ti=12345&pa=refund
```

The response code was a `200`, however, I did this last week and the refund still isn't showing - so it's not worked.

The `tid` parameter is updated with my analytics account ID and the `ti` parameter is the order number.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you turn on Enhanced Ecommerce?
From docs `You can measure refunds in only views (profiles) that have enabled Enhanced Ecommerce. You can't measure refunds in traditional Ecommerce.`

Comment: Yea it's enabled

Comment: There is an extra slash after the /collect and before the question mark symbol.
You always receive HTTP 200 from the GA collection endpoint no matter what :)